# When I log into my friends minecraft server I fall through the world continuously

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack

My friends and I are trying to play the Yogscast Complete pack on a server he has set up on his computer.

When it is just me and him on the server, everything is okay, when I spawn I will fall through the world for about 4 seconds then everything will sync and will be good to go.

However, when someone else tries to join, I start to lag and the friend will just keep falling through the world until I get the message "End of Stream"

He has 10GB of RAM dedicated to the server, has cable internet and any other mod pack works normally when he hosts.
Is there some way we can see why this happens, or error codes we can look up?

Any insight would be a great help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for a modded server.  We only support vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: The only thing I can get out of this is "GET BETTER INTERNET!"

Answer (score 1):

The reason you fall through the world is because the chunk is not loaded yet where you are going to spawn... You can fix this by having either a entity (a horse, npc) with a name tag or some chunk loader mod or plugin. 
The "End of stream" error occurs when the user can't successfully connect to the server(this dose not mean that the server is down, it just means that the users connection isnt strong enough to connect to the server. Its like running but not knowing where to go...). The only thing to fix this is better Internet connection on both ends.